# Piece that goes screwed in my steam wand

Tags: espresso, espresso-machine, latte, latte-art

I bought a espresso machine for home. The machine I bought is a Ikohs Kaffeta.

It has a screwable piece that goes in the tip of the steam wand that it is used to create foam (as the manual says).

I see some other home espresso machines come with what it's called an auto-frothing wand, and basically is a piece that you can remove to make the wand work like a normal wand for creating more micro foam milk.
I tried removing that piece but it only heats the liquid and creates a lot of bubbles.
I can only put air into the milk and make a whirl using that piece. The thing is that I am tring to create more of a microfoam for trying latte art but I end up getting a thick layer of dense foam (which I also like) but I want to be able to create micro-foamy milk.
I get nothing like elastic milk.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a wand with a single tip at the end?

To get microfoam, you only have to produce a little foam at the start of steaming, a few light 'rips' of bubbles, then the rest of the time is spent whirling this into the milk. Keep the wand tip just below the milk and a little to the side while keeping the pitcher flat. This will create a whirlpool that helps mix everything else up. Hope this helps.